# How to add a line break to a post title?

Tags: jekyll

```
---
layout: post
title: Markdown:<br>Style Guide
---
```

I expect this to produce

```
<h1>Markdown:<br>
Style Guide</h1>
```

But there are two issues. The colon breaks the Yaml. Hence I need to put " " around it.

```
---
layout: post
title: "Markdown:<br>Style Guide"
---
```

But what I can't solve is the line break in the title. It displays `<br>` instead of actually breaking the line. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably use a default Jekyll template which uses `{{ post.title | escape }}`.

If you remove the `escape` filter, all your html will be preserved.

It now reads : `{{ post.title }}` or `{{ page.title }}` depending on the context.